# Genetic Algorithms for computer security

Tags: security, firewall, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I am in the process of choosing project for uni. And I am really interested on combining genetic algorithms and computer security.

Therefore my question, **Is it possible to use GA on *any* aspect for computer security? For example?**. I was thinking something like a evolutionary firewall/anti-virus that will be able to self protect/inhibit threats. Is such thing plausible?

I really appreciate you guys input, advice, comments.

Comment: If they're your favourite subjects shouldn't you be the best one to answer your question?

Comment: I'm an undergrad, therefore my exposure to the topic is fairly limited. They are not my favourite, i said interested... for clarification, i meant in terms of "research".

Comment: @Carlos I find myself in the same situation as you. I see you posted this two years ago and surely there must have been some evolution in the field (or maybe GAs are irrelevant to computer security?) Have you done your paper? Is it available anywhere? Do you have resources that have not been posted here that could help me choose a project that combines GAs and Computer Security? (Unfortunately Google yields only limited and old results on this subject)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the whole idea of genetic algorithms is still being debated, i.e. if genetic algorithms are in any way better suited to solving optimization problems than other methods (who are either proven, easier to use, or provide other advantages).

That being said, yes, I know of a security-related application of genetic algorithms, mainly used in fuzzing to optimize code paths and therefore code coverage. There is a paper called [Vulnerability analysis for x86 executables using genetic algorithm and fuzzing](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4682289) and a BlackHat presentation predating that paper by two years called ["Sidewinder": An Evolutionary Guidance System for Malicious Input Crafting](http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-06/BH-US-06-Embleton.pdf)

Comment: wow buddy, thanks a lot. I need every paper i can get my hands on to.

Answer (score 3):

I briefly looked into this before, and there seems to be quite a bit of resources around [using genetic algorithms for network intrusion detection](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.89.3125). Hope it helps.

Comment: I already had that paper but thanks anyway buddy

Comment: There's a bunch of related resources on that google scholar list. Hope you find some of them useful

Comment: @JohnIdol The link is broken. Update please?

Comment: updated the link and this is the actual pdf: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.89.3125&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Stephanie Forrest's group's [work on computer immune systems](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~immsec/papers.htm). 
It's not traditional GAs, but it's very close. Hope that helps.